# Disable edit button from more tab bar application

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I am using Storyboard to create a tab bar which has 6 tabs. The tab bar is the initial view controller. I am not using any custom class for my tabbarcontroller.  The more tab gets a "edit" button. How can I remove that button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally created a custom class for my TabBarController and did this

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated {

    UINavigationBar *morenavbar = navigationController.navigationBar;
    UINavigationItem *morenavitem = morenavbar.topItem;
    /* We don't need Edit button in More screen. */
    morenavitem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

That solved it.

Answer (score 13):

Set the customizableViewControllers of your tabBarController to nil.

```
tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = nil;
```

Comment: This needs to be done after you have set the tabs on the tabBarController, if you change them

Comment: But where do you add this if you are using a storyboard like the question asks?